# Different native library for one of the product flavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My project has several Product Flavors which all of them share the same native library except for one that uses slightly different one with the same name.

Consider this is the build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    productFlavors {
        p0 {
        ....
        }
        p1 {
        ....
        }
        p2 {
        ....
        }
        p3 {
        ....
        }
        p4 {
        ....
        }
        p5 {
        ....
        }
    }
}
```

and this is folder structure:

```
src
...main
......jnilibs
.........armeabi-v7a
............lib1.so
...p5
......jnilibs
.........armeabi-v7a
............lib1.so
```

When I compile the p5 flavour it complains that lib1.so is duplicate (**Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK**) and it exists in multiple sources. It suggest to exclude this file, although I don't want to exclude but adding suggested code doesn't change anything. I know I can create different folders for each of the other flavors and put the same lib1.so in each jniLibs of them, but it's really not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who want to accomplish the same thing, best I found so far is to change the root of source set of packages which share the same library.

the build.gradle would be like this:

```
android {
    ...
    productFlavors {
        p0 {
        ....
        }
        p1 {
        ....
        }
        p2 {
        ....
        }
        p3 {
        ....
        }
        p4 {
        ....
        }
        p5 {
        ....
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        p0.setRoot("src/p")
        p1.setRoot("src/p")
        p2.setRoot("src/p")
        p3.setRoot("src/p")
        p4.setRoot("src/p")
    }
}
```

Folder structure:

```
src
...main
...p
......jnilibs
.........armeabi-v7a
............lib1.so
...p5
......jnilibs
.........armeabi-v7a
............lib1.so
```